# ggplot2 Extended Color Pallets

Tags: ggplot2, colors, palette

I've been using ggsci for quick access to a few standard journals... but there are only a dozen there.

Is there an extended color palette? Currently looking for Annals of Internal Medicine, but would love to know if there's a broad resources for journals.

Comment: Check out the scientific colormap https://blogs.egu.eu/divisions/gd/2017/08/23/the-rainbow-colour-map/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Viridis color palette at https://bids.github.io/colormap/ . The newer version of ggplot2 have a lite version built-in under https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_viridis.html . And there is also the full package at https://github.com/sjmgarnier/viridis .